# How to get rid of messages addressed to not existing subdomains?

Tags: sendmail, smtp, email

I have small problem with my sendmail server and need your little help :-)

My situation is as follow:

User mailboxes are placed on MS exchanege server and all mail to and from outside world are relayed trough my sendmail box.

```
Exchange server ----- sendmail server ------ Internet
```

My servers accept messages for one main domain (say, `my.domain.com`) and for few other domains (let we narrow  it too just one, say `my_other.domain.com`).  After configuring sendmail with showed bellow abbreviated `sendmail.mc` file, essentially everything works ok, but there is small problem. I want to reject messages addressed to not existing  recipients as soon as possible (to avoid sending non delivery reports), so my sendmail server make LDAP queries to exchange server, validating every recipient address. This works well both domains but not for subdomains. Such subdomains do not exist, but someone (I'm mean those heated spamers :-) could try addresses like this:

```
user@any_host.my.domain.com
```

or

```
user@any_host.my_other.domain.com
```

and for those addresses results are as follows:

1. Messages to `user@sendmail_hostname.my.domain.com` are rejected with error "Unknown user" (due to additional `LDAPROUTE_DOMAIN` line in my `sendmail.mc` file, and this is expected behaviour)
2. Messages to `user@any_other_hostname.my.domain.com` are rejected with error "Relaying denied". Little strange to me, why this time the error is different, but still ok. After all message was rejected and I don't care very much what error code will be returned to sender (spamer).
3. Messages to `user@sendmail_hostname.my_other.domain.com` and `user@any_other_hostname.my_other.domain.com` are rejected with error "Unknown user" but only when, there is no `user@my_other.domain.com` mailbox (on exchange server). If such mailbox exist, then all three addresses (i.e. `user@my_other.domain.com`, `user@sendmail_hostname.my_other.domain.com`  and `user@any_other_hostname.my_other.domain.com`) will be accepted. (adding additional line `LDAPROUTE_DOMAIN(my_sendmail_host.my_other.domain.com)` to my `sendmail.mc` file don't change anything)

My abbreviated `sendmail.mc` file is as follows (sendmail 8.14.3-5). Both domains are listed in `/etc/mail/local-host-names` file (`FEATURE(use_cw_file)` ):

```
define(`_USE_ETC_MAIL_')dnl
include(`/usr/share/sendmail/cf/m4/cf.m4')dnl
OSTYPE(`debian')dnl
DOMAIN(`debian-mta')dnl
undefine(`confHOST_STATUS_DIRECTORY')dnl        
define(`confRUN_AS_USER',`smmta:smmsp')dnl

FEATURE(`no_default_msa')dnl
define(`confPRIVACY_FLAGS',`needmailhelo,needexpnhelo,needvrfyhelo,restrictqrun,restrictexpand,nobodyreturn,authwarnings')dnl
FEATURE(`use_cw_file')dnl
FEATURE(`access_db', , `skip')dnl
FEATURE(`always_add_domain')dnl
MASQUERADE_AS(`my.domain.com')dnl
FEATURE(`allmasquerade')dnl
FEATURE(`masquerade_envelope')dnl

dnl define(`confLDAP_DEFAULT_SPEC',`-p 389 -h my_exchange_server.my.domain.com -b dc=my,dc=domain,dc=com')dnl 
dnl define(`ALIAS_FILE',`/etc/aliases,ldap:-k (&(|(objectclass=user)(objectclass=group))(proxyAddresses=smtp:%0)) -v mail')dnl

FEATURE(`ldap_routing',, `ldap -1 -T<TMPF> -v mail -k proxyAddresses=SMTP:%0', `bounce')dnl
LDAPROUTE_DOMAIN(`my.domain.com')dnl
LDAPROUTE_DOMAIN(`my_other.domain.com ')dnl
LDAPROUTE_DOMAIN(`my_sendmail_host.my.domain.com')dnl
define(`confLDAP_DEFAULT_SPEC', `-p 389 -h "my_exchange_server.my.domain.com" -d "CN=sendmail,CN=Users,DC=my,DC=domain,DC=com" -M simple -P /etc/mail/ldap-secret -b "DC=my,DC=domain,DC=com"')dnl

FEATURE(`nouucp',`reject')dnl
undefine(`UUCP_RELAY')dnl
undefine(`BITNET_RELAY')dnl
define(`confTRY_NULL_MX_LIST',true)dnl
define(`confDONT_PROBE_INTERFACES',true)dnl
define(`MAIL_HUB',` my_exchange_server.my.domain.com.')dnl
FEATURE(`stickyhost')dnl

MAILER_DEFINITIONS
MAILER(smtp)dnl
```

Could someone more experienced with sendmail advice my how to reject messages to those unwanted subdomains?

P.S. Mailboxes `@my_other.domain.com` are used only for receiving messages and never for sending.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the [configuration README](http://www.sendmail.com/sm/open_source/docs/configuration_readme/) you will see that using MAIL_HUB redirects all incoming mail to a centralized hub. Since you have LDAP routing comment out the MAIL_HUB entry.

Comment: I have tried removing MAIL_HUB directive, but then **all** messages addressed to `any_user@my_other.domain.com` are rejected with error "User unknown". I think that I need right  combination of MAIL_HUB, stickyhost and LOCAL_RELAY, but could not figure it out.

Comment: Is user1@my.domain.com equivalent to user1@my_other.domain.com ?

Comment: Sometimes. Every user1@my_other.domain.com has also address user1@my.domain.com, but the opposite is not always true.

Comment: First of all, you do not need MAIL_HUB. Now let us concentrate on the "User unknown" error for @my_other.doman.com users. What happens when you query the Exchange server via LDAP from the sendmail host for those users from the command line?

Comment: I'm sorry but I could not construct valid ldapsearch command (it has different option letters from ldap client build into sendmail). Could you show me how should I do this? (I have already tried:  ldapsearch -p 389 -h my_exchange_host -D "CN=user_name,CN=Users,DC=my,DC=domain,DC=com"  -y /etc/mail/ldap-secret -b "DC=my,DC=domain,DC=com"  -v mail  "(&(|(objectclass=user)(objectclass=group))(proxyAddresses=smtp:user@my_other.domain.com))" , but receive error: "ldap_sasl_interactive_bind_s: Unknown authentication method (-6)". I'm Sorry, but I completely don't understand LDAP.

Comment: Do you have the GSSAPI libraries installed on your system? Does the error message come with an "additional info" message?

Comment: I suppose yes - I have installed package libgssglue1 (with file /usr/lib/libgssglue.so.1.0.0). But LDAP queries works from sendmail. Using recipient address `user@any_host.my_other.domain.com`, sendmail server responses with code 250 if there is mailbox  for 'user' and with code 550 whet such mailbox does not exist. Problem is that when user mailbox exist (f.e. 'user@my_other.domain.com') it responses with code 250 also for address 'user@anything.my_other.domain.com'. I think it is more sendmail problem than LDAP.

Comment: If you have MAIL_HUB defined, how do you know that sendmail queries Exchange? Do you tcpdump port 389 or have relevant logs that show that LDAP queries for @domain.com are executed?

Comment: Because my sendmail server themselves knows nothing about existence or not existence of particular mailboxes, but nevertheless it responses correctly with code 250 if user mailbox exist or 550 when not. It can check it only with LDAP ...

Comment: Remove MAIL_HUB, keep stickyhost and keep only your domain.com. Does it still work for user@domain.com? If yes, then add my_other.domain.com. Try to locate errors in the Exchange logs to see what is queried

Comment: FWIW, I have solved this problem on our systems using MIMEDefang and md_check_against_smtp_server() and not LDAP

Comment: Thank you for your efforts. I have also solved this in similar manner - by adding `*@*.my.domain.com` and `*@*.my_other.domain.com` to spamassassin blacklist. This way unwanted messages are accepted, but at last are definitely marked as a spam (that's why I call it "workaround" only)

Comment: Well there's an even better solution, assuming that for example bit-bucket is aliased to /dev/null. See http://pastebin.com/4qDgnRCC on how to modify ruleset 0 to silently discard them.